# Why Does typeof array[0] == 'undefined' Not Work?

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof

I want to check if the next element in the array exists before performing actions on it, but I can't check if it is undefined or not. For example:

```
// Variable and array are both undefined
alert(typeof var1);   // This works
alert(typeof arr[1]); // This does nothing

var arr = [1,1];
alert(typeof arr[1]); // This works now
```

Comment: Check your console for errors!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert(typeof arr[1]); // This does nothing
```

It doesn't do anything because it's failing with an error:

```
ReferenceError: arr is not defined
```

If you try it this way instead:

```
var arr = [];
alert(typeof arr[1]);
```

Then you'll get what you expect. However, a better way to do this check would be to use the `.length` property of the array:

```
// Instead of this...
if(typeof arr[2] == "undefined") alert("No element with index 2!");

// do this:
if(arr.length <= 2) alert("No element with index 2!");
```

Comment: ^this. To expand on the first line of non-code: the javascript engine gets through `alert(typeof arr` just fine, but because `arr` is not an array at that point, the javascript engine throws an error when you try to access an element of it (`[1]`), and stops executing that statement.

Comment: @joequincy No, it has nothing to do with being an array or not: it is a ReferenceError at that point (not a failed property lookup or otherwise). For instance (to re-iterate the response example), in `a = {}; alert(typeof a[1])` there is no ReferenceError (as `a` can be resolved in scope) and `a[1]` will quite happily evaluate to `undefined`.

Comment: To be specific: a `ReferenceError` occurs because JavaScript attempts to dereference `arr` to look up `arr[1]`, before `typeof`'s logic is invoked. Because `arr` does not exist, trying to dereference it (which is what the `[1]` does) fails.

Comment: @pst Yes, it has everything to do with the fact that at that point in the code, `arr` is not _a type of variable that supports property lookups_. Of course, that phrasing is extremely cumbersome, so I typed "array" instead because it's the type that is actually relevant to the situation. And you'll note that at no point did I state that it only applies to arrays.

Comment: @Ambder I prefer view it the other way: it is not that a "dereference" is forced, but rather that the expression (`a` in `a[1]`) is not treated as a *reference type* (only the `1` property would be, but by that time it's too late as `a` failed to evaluate) ..

Comment: @joequincy No that is incorrect, however. I have provided a counter-example, so as Amber has. This is valid, but useless, JavaScript: `var x = 1; x[2] = 3`. A ReferenceError occurs *before* a value is evaluated (or rather, is thrown when a variable/property *can't* be resolved). If a variable/property can be resolved it will evaluate to something. If a property is not set it will evaluate to undefined when evaluated.

Comment: @pst That's not really correct - consider the output of `undefined[1]` - `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.

Comment: @pst So basically, you're saying I'm wrong based on things that are unrelated to my response?

Comment: @joequincy I am saying the following is incorrect: "..but because arr is not an array at that point, the javascript engine throws an error when you try to access an element of it.."

Comment: @Amber Ah, yes. Of course. I wasn't disagree with that; I view evaluation ("dereferencing") as the normal, not the exceptional case so I view the special case when an expression is used as a reference type value and omit talking about "dereferencing" in JavaScript.

Comment: @pst Keep in mind, you also get a `ReferenceError` if you try to say `a == 2` but `a` isn't defined. ReferenceErrors have nothing to do with "reference types" and everything to do with trying to operate on variables that don't exist.

Comment: @Amber I am using "reference type" to mean the [Reference Specification Type](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7); I guess I should be more explicit with that name. (ECMAScript does not use the term for any other types .. bloody language cross-overs :-/)

Comment: @pst in this particular instance (using a `typeof` statement), you'll find that I'm quite correct. Try this in the console: `{console.log(typeof a, typeof a[1]);}{var b=[];console.log(typeof b, typeof b[1]);}`

Comment: @joequincy The first throws a ReferenceError (as `a` does not exist in scope) and the 2nd evaluates to `undefined` for `typeof b[1]`. However, try with a value that is *not* an array: `var c = 123.456; console.log(typeof c[1]);`, which will also evaluate to `undefined` just fine. Now, `undefined[1]` or `null[1]`, as pointed out by Amber, is a different case yet .. but the issue isn't with "not [being] an array".

Comment: @pst Then my console (Chrome) is doing something funky, because `typeof a` is logging `undefined` and `typeof a[1]` is throwing a `TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.

Comment: @joequincy It sounds like `a` might already exist as a property (this has burned me several times in the past). Try a different/never-used variable name or `del a` first. Otherwise, I don't know :) - In any case, have a merry holidays, if such timing befalls you!

Comment: @pst Checked that. It doesn't exist, and I get the same thing if I sub `kwljerarsesdije` for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

when working with arrays, before you access an array index you should also check the array itself.

wrong:

```
if (arr[0] == ...)
```

good:

```
if (typeof arr != "undefined" and arr[0]==......
```